# How to declare function pointer parameter

Tags: c, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

What is the difference between these 2 declarations:

```
double math_operation(double x, double (*func)(double));
double math_operation(double x, double func(double));
```

They both seem to work with the same exact call in GCC:

```
math_operation(2.0, sqrt);
```

Is it just syntactic sugar or is there more to it?

Comment: Also: `typedef double (*dd_func)(double);` then `double math_operation(double, dd_func);`

Comment: @Fredrik - The second one is *very much* C. Function declarations enjoy the same treatment as array declarations in parameter lists. They decay.

Comment: @Milag I am not asking for advice on how to declare parameters, I was just asking from a theoretical (and pedantic) standpoint. I know how ugly function pointers can get in real code :)

Comment: @DarkAtom - You shouldn't allow yourself to be led astray by someone whose not willing to post an answer where it may be peer reviewed and voted upon.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Any idea why the first form is prevalent? While the second one seem much more readable and clean.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I imagine it's because we all learned C the same way. Monkey C, monkey do. Then it becomes a habit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because it creates a lot of confusion. If you declare a variable `double (*func)(double);` inside a scope body, it is a function pointer. If you declare `double func(double);`, it is a forward declaration of `func()`. The second form in parameter declarations is more readable, but is very strange to me.

Comment: @DarkAtom - I think far more confusion grows out of arrays decaying. There's hardly anyone who ever learned C that didn't stumble upon trying to pass multi-dimensional arrays as pointers to pointers. The discrepency in function declarations is far more negligible in its potential confusion.

Comment: The first version is the way it was done in traditional C.  Making the indirection symbol optional was added later. Personally I don't like the way they support clearly different declarations as if they were the same.  It would be preferable if they only supported a single, consistent format.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's true, but once you learn it you can very much pray nothing changes. I guess that's what we can expect from a language developed in the 70s.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: This business about using pointers-to-pointers for multidimensional arrays is strange. I do not recall seeing it before 2000, maybe later. Is anybody really using it in high-quality production code, or is it just something that caught root among amateurs or certain schools and has spread? When I learned C, and for some time later, there was no stumbling between arrays and pointers-to-pointers because people were not using pointers-to-pointers for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I've never seen it in production quality code. Which is not surprising, because we learn it's not correct pretty fast. I learned C after the turn of the century, so I can't comment on how it was before. It may just be that myself and others I encountered were taught in a really flawed way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I guess it's because more and more people wanted multi-dimensional dynamically allocated arrays. The thing that is never taught in schools is that you can use pointers to VLAs for that: `int (*arr)[M] = malloc(N * M * sizeof(int));` (where N are rows and M are columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two function declarations

```
double math_operation(double x, double (*func)(double));
double math_operation(double x, double func(double));
```

declare the same one function. You may include the both declarations in your program though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant declarations.

The compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter having a function type to parameter of pointer type to the function.

On the other hand, a function designator used as an argument is converted to pointer to the function.

[Note: in general all these function declarations declare the same one function

```
double math_operation( double, double (*)( double ) );
double math_operation( double, double( double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double (*)( double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double( double ) );
double math_operation( double, double (*)( const double ) );
double math_operation( double, double( const double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double (*)( const double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double( const double ) );
```

Also the pointer to the function itself can have the qualifier `const`

```
double math_operation( double, double ( * const )( double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double ( * const )( double ) );
double math_operation( double, double ( * const )( const double ) );
double math_operation( const double, double ( * const )( const double ) );
```

-end note.]

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

Comment: Well this clarifies everything. It is just syntactic sugar, just like `int*` vs `int[]` as parameter. Thank you!

Comment: @DarkAtom You are write. And a function designator used as an argument is implicitly converted to pointer to the function.

Comment: Well I get confuse by all of those `const`s now, but I get your point. But I think that for `const double` the compiler may make some optimizations so that the parameter is passed by reference and not by value (since it cannot change).

Comment: @DarkAtom The qualifier constant is another story.:) If a parameter is declared as a constant it is ignored when the function type is determined.:)

Comment: So that means that such optimizations cannot be made then. I guess you can always use `const double*` for that. I guess it's the same story with `volatile`?

Comment: @DarkAtom const double * is not a constant parameter. It is a non-constant pointer to constant data. A constant pointer will look like const double * const.

Comment: With `const X*` you are passing a reference (pointer) to X, and X cannot be modified through it. With `const X` you are copying X and not allowing the function to modify the copy. It's pointless to use the second form, that's what I was trying to say. Anyway, this is off-topic :)

Comment: There are 4 more cases with `double math_operation(double, double (* const)(double ) );`...

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right. I will update my answer.:)

Comment: (Well, a side note, there are x4 more cases with `volatile`, don't... ;)

Comment: @KamilCuk I will stop at the listed declarations.:)